# sweetalert js add content with id and run jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert2

I build website with html, css, javascript and jquery.

I added content to [sweet alert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) and add element with id

```
   var share_friends = function(e){
swal({
  title: "<i>Title</i>", 
  content: share_social,
  button: "V <u>redu</u>", 
});
}

var share_social = document.createElement("div");
share_social.id = 'share'
```

and I want to add piece of jquery code that when I open the alert it add dynamic content of [socials shares](http://js-socials.com/)
 so i added this piece of code

```
  $("#share").jsSocials({
        shares: ["email", "twitter", "facebook", "googleplus", "linkedin", "pinterest", "stumbleupon", "whatsapp"]
    });
```

but it's not do nothing.

but when I add into my html code (hard-code) the div with the id share it works fine.
e.g

```
<div id = "share"></div>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: well it appears you never add the div to the document.

Comment: I checked and i added it but the jquery not run when it added dynamiclly

Comment: Do you append the div to the page?

Comment: yes.I checked when i see in debug mode then Elements and it added new div

Comment: It would be nice if the code showed it and how things are called.